# LINQ advice on selecting distinct elements from a collection

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

I need to select distinct highways from a roads collection.

I suppose I could use LINQ for this.

I have (stub code)

```
  Dim roads As List(Of Roads) = myRegion.Roads
  Dim highways As New List(Of Highway)

  For Each road In roads
    If road.RoadType = RoadType.Highway Then
      highways.Add(DirectCast(road, Highway))
    End If
  Next ic

  ' Now I think sorting them by .Id and then remove duplicates '
  Dim myComparer As New HighwayByIdComparer
  highways.Sort(myComparer)
```

C# variants are accepted as well ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C#:

```
return myRegion.Roads
    .Where(x => x.RoadType == RoadType.Highway)
    .DistinctBy(x => x.Id);
```

(where **DistinctBy** is an extension method defined in Jon Skeet's excellent [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) project)

Comment: ok... but I didn't finish my code, because I need to select distinct (with different .ID) elements

Comment: I am not sure if I can use MoreLINQ in a commercial proprietary project.

Comment: Take inspiration from the source and write your own implementation then - http://morelinq.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs

Comment: ok... you maybe don't need the OrderBy, cause I did the sorting just to easier eliminate the duplicates... )

Comment: also, I should note that the `OfType<Highway>` is less performant that `road.RoadType = RoadType.Highway`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I didn't get the original requirement, changed OrderBy to GroupBy/Select First. You can also simply use `Distinct` if you override the Equals method to compare the Ids

```
var highways = roads.OfType<Highway>()
          .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
          .Select(x => x.First())
          .ToList()
```

or in VB.Net:

```
Dim highways = roads.OfType(Of Highway)().
       GroupBy(Function(road) road.Id).
       Select(Function(x) x.First()).
       ToList()
```

Comment: OfType is clever but you're missing the Distinct.

Comment: Best solution in my opinion, you can remove the HighwayByIdComparer as well

Comment: And OrderBy isn't called for, that was a (half-way) solution to get Distinct.

Answer (score 1):

> 'Road model

```
Public Class Road
Public Property Id As Integer
Public Property Name As String
Public Property RoadType As RoadType
End Class
```

> 'Highway model

```
Public Class Highway
Public Property Id As Integer
Public Property Name As String 
End Class
```

> 'RoadType Enum

```
Public Enum RoadType

Residential
Highway
OffRoad
End Enum
```

> 'Highway comparer (used in the distinct clause)

```
Public Class HigwayNameComparer
Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Highway)
Public Function Equals(ByVal x As Highway, ByVal y As Highway) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Highway).Equals
    Return x.Name = y.Name
End Function

Public Function GetHashCode(ByVal obj As Highway) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Highway).GetHashCode
    Return obj.Name.GetHashCode()
End Function
End Class
```

> 'Console app

```
Sub Main()
    Dim roads As New List(Of Road)
    roads.Add(New Road() With {.Id = 1, .Name = "Barclays Road", .RoadType = RoadType.Residential})
    roads.Add(New Road() With {.Id = 2, .Name = "Effie Road", .RoadType = RoadType.Residential})
    roads.Add(New Road() With {.Id = 3, .Name = "Out Road", .RoadType = RoadType.OffRoad})
    roads.Add(New Road() With {.Id = 4, .Name = "M4", .RoadType = RoadType.Highway})
    roads.Add(New Road() With {.Id = 5, .Name = "M4", .RoadType = RoadType.Highway})


    Dim results = (From road In roads Where road.RoadType = RoadType.Highway
            Select New Highway With {.Id = road.Id, .Name = road.Name}).Distinct(New HigwayNameComparer())


    For Each highway As Highway In results
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", highway.Name)
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()


End Sub
```

--- Output : M4

Answer (score 0):

First, you could take a look on this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/03/25/how-to-use-linq-methods-to-compare-objects-of-custom-types.aspx . This indicates that you need to create `EqualityComparer<T>` and than simply pass it to `Distinct` operator.

```
roads.Where(r => r.RoadType == RoadType.Highway).Distinct(myComparer);
```

Assuming that myComparer actually implements `EqualityComaprer<T>` correctly.

Comment: `Dim myComparer As New HighwayByIdComparer`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom equality comparer for `Road` to use `Distinct()`:

```
public class RoadComparer : IEqualityComparer<Road>
{
    public bool Equals(Road x, Road y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Road obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}

var results = myRegion.Roads
                      .OfType<Highway>()
                      .Distinct(new RoadComparer())
                      .OrderBy( road => road.Id)
                      .ToList();
```